# Google Sheets Date Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a personal finances Google Sheet with all my expenditures (column A) and corresponding dates (column B) of the month when they are due to be paid.

I would like to create a formula that shows me what is left for the remainder of the month depending on what day of the month I am looking at the sheet.

Something like, ifDate is today, sum all remaining dates of the month expenses.

TIA

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1onq-ZlocmNWzo79_o_7FIJSW4UBzBD5evPyOrVVxEtk/edit?usp=sharing @Harun24hr

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula** it works even if the dates is disordered.

```
=SUMIF(C2:C,">"&F2,B2:B)
```

[image]

### Update

```
=SUMIF(D3:D,">"&TODAY(),C3:C)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that formula isn't accurate.

Comment: It needs a greater than ">" symbol.

Comment: Good note the answer is updated.